# I cannot type "@" in a text input after i updated Flash professional CC to Animate CC

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textinput

After I updatet my Flash Professional to Animate CC, I cant seem to be able to type in any of the special characters into a text input. I've tried restricting it, but that doesn't work.
The reason i need this is because we got a task in out IT class in school to make a signup page for a company, but noone was able to get the e-mail text input have
"@".

Comment: Sorry, i've added some more info now :)

Comment: If you have restricted some characters make sure you have included the "@" character. And if you are using a custom font make sure the font has the "@" character included (some fonts have only letters and numbers included)

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't your code - if you haven't added a 
myTextInput.restrict = 'A-Z' or anything like that. Two things you need to do.

1. Ensure the font you are using has an '@' symbol (sounds crazy, but some don't.
2. More likely, you need to embed the font. Select the text field and in the properties windows there is an option to embed the font into the .swf file. Do this and select all (includes special characters).

Good luck!